# Проблема с Apache на XAMPP

Tags: apache, php, mysql

Работал хорошо, до сегодняшнего включения: SQL запускается, а Апач нет. Подскажите почему?
Уже переустанавливал. ОС Windows XP SP2.

Comment: Просьба Денвер не предлагать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень часто апач не запускается потому что уже запущен скайп или аська, которые используют порт 80. Если дело в них, то запускайте их после того как запустите апач, а еще лучше в их настройках переназначьте порты. Сам пользуюсь xampp, тоже не мог понять почему не запускался апач, пока не выключил скайп.

Answer (score 1):

Апач может не запускаться по [разным](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-windows.html#557) причинам, например:

1. запущено больше одного веб-сервера одновременно;
2. работу Апача блокируют другие программы, использующие порт 80;
3. в системе работает брэндмауэр (или антивирус), блокирующий порт апача;

Для начала - посмотреть логи:

> `more < "c:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log"`

и если есть ошибка, устранить ее.

Comment: Не все понял в error.log но xampp раньше работал точнее в 6 утра,потом перестал запускаться ,не смог исправить поставил Denwer(я вроде как новичок),работает нормально,продолжаю изучать PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Апачу нужен еще 443 порт, может быть он занят (например SVN стоит)